# How To Retrieve Token From An Expressjs API with Angular

Tags: angularjs, express

Hi this is is my first project using angular, how can I retrieve tokens from an express API?

Comment: Please perform **some** sort of research before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please, paste your code and explain your problem.

I suppose that you are looking for token auth in a AngularJS + ExpressJS app, so you can follow this [link](https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth) it talks about json web tokens.

You can use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-simple) for generate your jwt (jsonwebtoken) and send it to Angular, then in Angular you can use [this lib](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) for get the jwt from the response.

These are easy to implements and so useful.

Hope it helps you